# Can you just put 99 for values over 100?

Tags: usability, website-design

I have tabs that navigate to different list, and a badge button on each tab that displays how many values are in each list. It's difficult to fit  3 numbers into the small badge button. If I extend the badge button too much, it looks odd for the numbers 1-9. When I put 99+, you can barely read it.

My question is, is it OK to put 99 for values that are over 100? We have a max of 100 anyway, so I was wondering if users understand that 99 means it's filled or if I need the plus at the end.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'd consider using a smaller font for 100. As "1" is rather thin and "00" is about as wide as "99", it doesn't need to be much smaller.

Comment: If the actual amount isn't so important to the User, why show a number at all?

Comment: You can do a super-unconvential approach and write "C" for the roman numeral for 100

Comment: @PerAlexandersson this is a user friendly system buddy! hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could think about making the badge buttons width dynamically adjust to the content, giving you a circle with 1-2 numbers and a lozenge effect with 100.

As you point out, 100 is an edge case so probably won't come too frequently to worry about the slightly off design element.

From a usability perspective you should always try to provide the user with accurate feedback as to the state of the system. 99 for 100 items is dishonest and may lead users to lose trust in other areas of your tool, specifically around counting and totals.

100 would be fine, 99+ would be fine, >99 at a stretch could be used but these are all three characters, hence my original suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up just using a smaller font for 100

Answer (score 1):

On Mobile chrome, if you have more than 99 tabs open, the display becomes :D 
I find it pretty funny given that the number of opened tab tends to become irrelevant when you have so much opened.

If the number is still relevant I would still prefer the selected solution of dougajmcdonald